# How to select table values from combobox selection?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I'm using an Access 2003 database and have 2 comboboxes I am trying to work with. The first box I have perfected already, which is a dropdown of different tables (categories of parts). Once that table is selected, I want to be able to look at the part numbers within that category through a dropdown box selection. From here I want to be able to pull up the correct report for that category with that part number in it so I can print a report for every part number. I'm sure I'll have to write some sort of VBA, Query or Macro AfterUpdate() code, but I just don't know how to fill that second combobox with the selected table's part numbers.

[Click here for an image of my Menu layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JySh.png)

Here's my Query for the first box to show the tables I want:

```
    SELECT Msysobjects.Name
    FROM Msysobjects
    WHERE (((Msysobjects.Name)  not Like "MSYS*" 
    And (Msysobjects.Name) not like "_*"
    And (Msysobjects.Name) not like "~*"
    ) AND ((Msysobjects.Type)=1))
   ORDER BY Msysobjects.Name;
```

And I think this is what I'll need to print after the second box has it's selection:

```
    Private Sub partnumberselect_AfterUpdate()
    DoCmd.OpenTable Forms![_Datasheet Printing].Form.TagLabelSelection.Column(1), acViewNormal
    End Sub
```

Thank you in advance and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the example below.

```
Private Sub cboCountry_AfterUpdate()
    On Error Resume Next
    cboCity.RowSource = "Select tblAll.City " & _
        "FROM tblAll " & _
        "WHERE tblAll.Country = '" & cboCountry.Value & "' " & _
        "ORDER BY tblAll.City;"
End Sub
```

[image]

You can read all about this concept, and others, in the link below.

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut10.htm

Comment: Thank you!! Example 1 from that link was perfect, I just entered in all of the cases

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting what are called "cascading comboboxes" which means the second box is dependent on the selection of the first.

This is accomplished through the control source of the second combo box.

The first thing you should do is write a query that returns all possible options of the second combobox, without caring so much about filtering it based on the first combo selection. Once you have it returning the correct data, you will add a `WHERE` clause to the second box's control source that's something like:

`WHERE Msysobjects.Name Like Forms![_Datasheet Printing]!TagLabelSelection.Value`

This is referencing your first combobox on your form. So after a selection is made in the first combobox, the underlying control source of the second will have the proper criteria to return the appropriate options.

*However,* you will need to add some VBA to the `AfterUpdate()` event on the **first** combobox. Once the selection is made, you need the second box to refresh the control source to populate the correct selections. The code is simply:

`Forms![_Datasheet Printing]![MySecondComboboxName].Requery`

Comment: This makes sense, so thank you! I am completely new to VB and Access, so writing the query to return all possible options of the combobox is giving me trouble. If I do:

        Select CATALOG from COM(one of the tables)

I get the results back that I want from the COM table. The problem is pulling the catalog column from another ~20 tables.

Comment: @ChristinaDocenko sounds like your tables may be denormalized. Did you structure the tables? Either way, look into data normalization and assess whether your structure is correct before developing further. Denormalized tables make queries unnecessarily complex, and in some cases, impossible to build.

Comment: @ChristinaDocenko Pulling the Catalog number from multiple tables is unnecessarily complex. If you need assistance with normalization feel free to start a new question. Parting advice: Look at the 20 tables, do they more or less all have the same columns? If so, is the only difference the table name? Can the category represented by the table name be moved into a new column of a combined table? Ie. "Screwdrivers" "Drill Bits" "Saws" as separate tables could be combined with a "Category" field designating each row as either a screwdriver, drill bit, or saw.

Comment: This is exactly the case. Ideally, I'd make a master table with all of the category titles and their info in it, however, the data is added in through Autocad Electrical and for some reason automatically separates the data into the separate tables. I could use an append query to add these new entries into the master table, though. I might just do that, thank you!